# How to make image and text on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I've got a nav bar and I'm trying to have the logo and text on the same line as each other and the links. Also, my links are in the wrong order so I want to know why that is and how to fix it?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```css
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
}

#nav li {
  float: right;
}

#nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" >
  <ul >
    <p style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; margin-top:2px"><img src='images/DBA 
  LOGO.png 'width="30" height="30" style="float:left">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Home </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Courses </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Log in </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Trainers </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Enterprise </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Never use `float` in design, unless it's an image in a text-block.

Answer (score 1):

I simplify your snippet and rewrite the css. Please note it is not valid to put `<p>` under `<ul>`. Introducing [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav), ideal for navigation. You don't have to `float` everything. `float: right` put the first element to to the most right, that's why the menu order is reverse. You can shift the whole navigation to right using `text-align: right`. Finally, to align the logo with the company name, I set its `line-height` to `30px`, same as the `<img>` height.

```css
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 2px;
    float: left;
}

#company-name {
    line-height: 30px;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
}

nav {
    text-align: right;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav">

        <p id="logo" style="">
            <img src='images/DBA LOGO.png ' width="30" height="30" style="float: left"> <label id="company-name">DIGITAL
                BUCKET COMPANY</label>
        </p>
        <nav>

            <a> Home </a> <a> Courses </a> <a> Log in </a> <a> Trainers </a> <a> Enterprise </a>

        </nav>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `p` is valid children of `ul`, it's bad html so move p tag in `nav` id
- second you can set layout using `flexbox` and remove `float:right` from `li`

```css
#nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
  /*float: right;*/
  display:inline-block;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" >
  <p style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; margin:0"><img src='images/DBA 
  LOGO.png 'width="30" height="30" style="float:left">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
  <ul>    
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Home </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Courses </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Log in </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Trainers </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Enterprise </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all `float` properties and use `flexbox`.
Add flexbox properties to `ul`, have it take the whole space and align items to the center; clear the inherited margins of your p and let it grow;  remove `float: right` from the `li` item.

Also note that you should not have a `<p>` inside `<ul>`

```css
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#nav p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
<p><img src='images/DBA 
  LOGO.png ' width="30" height="30" style="float:left">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
<li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Home </a></li>
<li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Courses </a></li>
<li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Log in </a></li>
<li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Trainers </a></li>
<li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Enterprise </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added new CSS, Hope this helps.

```css
p {
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

   

#nav li {
  float: right;
}

#nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" >
  <ul >
    <p style="vertical-align:middle; margin-top:2px"><img src='images/DBA 
  LOGO.png 'width="30" height="30" style="">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Home </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Courses </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Log in </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Trainers </a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Enterprise </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- its better practice to put only `<li>` inside `<ul>`
- check flexbox

```css
*{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #nav{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #D4D4D4;
        }
        #nav p{
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        
        }

        #nav li {
            float: left;
        }

        #nav li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

       

        /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
   
    <div id="nav" >
        <p><img src='images/DBA 
            LOGO.png 'width="30" height="30">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
        <ul>
            <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Home </a></li>
            <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Courses </a></li>
            <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Log in </a></li>
            <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Trainers </a></li>
            <li style="text-align:right;"> <a> Enterprise </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```